# Notepad++ join lines following pattern match

Tags: notepad++

I'm getting up to speed on using RegEx in Notepad++. How would I merge lines following every time a MAC address is found? So find lines that have 5 : and 12 characters with 2 characters between each : and merge that line and all following lines until the next MAC

This is what I have

```
12:34:4b:17:3a:4a
iOS
Barney
BarneyZ/10.20.7.138
BigHouse Wireless Users
BH New Office NW corner
7
11
802.11b/g
99%
Authorized
EAP
```

And I want it like:

```
12:34:4b:17:3a:4a iOS Barney BarneyZ/10.20.7.138 BigHouse Wireless Users BH New Office NW corner 7 11 802.11b/g 99% Authorized EAP
```

with CSV delimiters?

How do I do that in Notepad++? thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where are the CSV delimiters in your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace all linebreak NOT followed by a MAC with a single space.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!([a-f0-9]{2})(?::(?1)){5})`
- Replace with:  # a space or anything you want
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R                  # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!                 # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after
    ([a-f0-9]{2})   # group 1, 2 hexa characters
    (?:             # non capture group
        :(?1)       # a colon followed by same pattern as defined in group 1 (i.e 2 hexa characters)
    ){5}            # end group, must appear 5 times
)                   # end lookahead
```

---

I ran this in a file that contains 3 times your example, it gives:

```
12:34:4b:17:3a:4a iOS Barney BarneyZ/10.20.7.138 BigHouse Wireless Users BH New Office NW corner 7 11 802.11b/g 99% Authorized EAP
12:34:4b:17:3a:4a iOS Barney BarneyZ/10.20.7.138 BigHouse Wireless Users BH New Office NW corner 7 11 802.11b/g 99% Authorized EAP
12:34:4b:17:3a:4a iOS Barney BarneyZ/10.20.7.138 BigHouse Wireless Users BH New Office NW corner 7 11 802.11b/g 99% Authorized EAP
```

Comment: `merge lines following every time a MAC address is found` which probably means lines before it should be left intact.

Comment: @revo: May be, but I assume the file contains only blocks that begin with MAC. Wait for OP's comment.